# Advantage Database Server 11 connection string for Code First

Tags: advantage-database-server

I am having problem with ADS11 connection string for code first,

I've tried many way but I couldn't make it.

Anybody know, please advice me.

Here is my working environment.

---

Server : Advantage Database Server 11

Path : \ADS_DB:6262\DB\DBB.ADD (Port : 6262)

Test Access Table : WEBORDERLN (ADT Type)

PK : PK (Char (36))

---

I downloaded Advantage.Data.Provider v11 and Advantage.Data.Entity v11.
And add to reference.

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Ads_Context" connectionString="Data Source=\\ADS_DB:6262\DB\DBB.ADD;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;ServerType=REMOTE;" providerName="Advantage.Data.Provider" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Controller,

```
public class Ads_Context : DbContext
{
    public Ads_Context(): base("name=Ads_Context")
{   
}
public DbSet<WebOrderLN> webOrderLns { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public string Index()
    {
        var context = new Ads_Context().webOrderLns.ToList(); // Source error point to here

        return "A";
    }

}
[Table("WEBORDERLN")]
public class WebOrderLN
{
    [Key]
    public string PK {get; set;}
    public string FK { get; set; }
    public string pickno { get; set; }
}
```

When I run above code, I got an error message,

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = HY000;   NativeError = 5174;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL][ASA] Error 5174:  Advantage failed to open the specified link.  dbo: Error 7041:  File not found.  Verify the specified path and file name is correct. Table name: WEBORDERLN  AdsCommand query execution failed.
```

Anybody know, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the schema name of ::this to your tables in code.

```
[Table( "WEBORDERLN", Schema = "::this" )]
public class WebOrderLN
{
    [Key]
    public string PK {get; set;}
    public string FK { get; set; }
    public string pickno { get; set; }
}
```

See this Knowledge Base Item
http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=17&RefNo=120423-2510